# Target Display Mode between two MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, target-disk-mode

I have TDM working with my iMac.  I am currently have two MacBook Pro (2012 and 2103) and was wondering if they support this?  I have not been able to get it to work.  Has anyone else gotten this to work?

I am currently running 10.10.2 on both computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only some of the non-5k display iMacs have target display mode. No MacBooks have (yet) had that capability as part of their hardware.

You'll need to do screen sharing or some other software solution if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

My macbook pro mid-2012 works fine with my iMac 2009.  It depends on the display port compatibility see item 4 in this link:

[Apple TDM mode compatability](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht3924)

So for example an earlier MBP without a Thunderbolt port, will not work with a later iMac that has a Thunderbolt port, although the reverse is fine.

I would expect MBP's after 2012 to work ok though.  You need to press Command + F2 together on the iMac keyboard.  If your keyboard settinhs are default, Fn keys are set to use the advanced functions, in which case you need to press Command+Fn+F2